# How do I create such a table in latex?

Tags: tables

[image]

Can someone please help me with creating such a table. I am having an issue with the colors and also fitting the table within my page. I would greatly appreciate it,thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline
Activity (2021)                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Apr}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{May}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Jun}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Jul}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Aug}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Sep}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Oct}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Nov}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Dec}              \\ 
\hline
Create research proposal                                                                                              & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Create questions}\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{ for interviews}                           &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Schedule interviews and \\conduct them\end{tabular}                                        &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Obtain relevant }\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{financial information}                     &                                      &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Create and send surveys to}\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{third-party logistics providers} &                                      &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
Create outline                                                                                                        &                                      &                                      &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
Write first draft                                                                                                     &                                      &                                      &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
Submission of first draft                                                                                             &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} &                                      &                                      &                                       \\ 
\hline
Write final draft using feedback                                                                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      &                                      & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.616,0.565,0.894}}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You have already asked a lot of simple questions and received answers that have not yet been accepted. You should also know by now that questions here should be about concrete things and questions like "Please do this complicated thing for me" are not welcome if not even an own approach in form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is presented.

Comment: I suggest to use an interface similar to word https://www.latex-tables.com/. Here you can create all the tables.

Comment: You may consider using the `nicematrix` or the `tabularray` package for a color table with horizontal and vertical lines though having so many horizontal and vertical lines is often considered 'not professional'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `pgfgantt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.616,0.565,0.894}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{ganttchart}[
     y unit title=0.75cm,
     x unit =0.8cm,
     vgrid,hgrid,
     title height=1,
     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=myblue},
     bar height=1,
     bar top shift=0,
     progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group height=.6,
     group peaks width={0.2}, 
     bar label node/.style={text width=6cm,
                            align=left,
                            anchor=east,
                            font=\small}
    ]{1}{9}
              
  \gantttitle{Apr}{1} \gantttitle{May}{1} \gantttitle{Jun}{1}
  \gantttitle{Jul}{1} \gantttitle{Aug}{1} \gantttitle{Sep}{1}
  \gantttitle{Oct}{1} \gantttitle{Nov}{1} \gantttitle{Dec}{1}\\
 
  \ganttbar{1. Create research proposal}
      {1}{1}\\
  \ganttbar{2. Create questions}
      {2}{2}\\
  \ganttbar{3. Schedule interviews and conduct them}
      {2}{3} \\
  \ganttbar{4. Obtain relevant financial information}
      {3}{3}\\ 
  \ganttbar{5. Create and send surveys to third-party logistics providers}
      {3}{3}\\
  \ganttbar{6. Create outline}
      {4}{4}\\ 
  \ganttbar{7. Write first draft}
      {4}{6} \\
  \ganttbar{8. Submission of first draft}
      {6}{6}\\
  \ganttbar{9. Write final draft using feedback}
      {7}{9}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing! I would love to use it but my document has "\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}" which I just realized I thought it was just normal article. Is there a tutorial or something where I can see how to adjust what you posted above to my documentclass type? 

Also, can I add "Activity 2021" right above the first task? Is there also somewhere I can read for this, thankss!!@leandriis

Comment: @DhruvNair: The code works perefctly fine with the documentclass options you mentioned in your comment. To prevent overlaps in the text, you may though want to use `text width=6cm` instead of `text width=4.6cm` which I used in my orginal answer. I just updated my answer accordingly (and also simplified the sode a bit). For more information on the details and settings, please refer to the [`pgfgantt` package manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt).

Answer (score 4):

Here there is a simple example of the use of latex-tables.com.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
  & A & C                                   & D                            & F                                & G                      \\ 
\hline
a &   & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.435,0.827,0.82}} dsgsdgs&                              &                                  &                        \\ 
\hline
b &   &                                     & {\cellcolor[rgb]{1,0.647,0}}dsgsdgs &                                  &                        \\ 
\hline
c &   &                                     &                              & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0,0.502,0.502}}shyshr &                        \\ 
\hline
d &   &                                     &                              &                                  & {\cellcolor{magenta}} adgag \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually using this site but I ran into the issue of my table going way over the page. I added a picture in the original question, thanks again

Comment: @DhruvNair Ok, but you can put your complete code like mine?

Comment: Done @Sebastiano

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in a comment, you may use the `nicematrix` to make such tables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{4cm}*{9}{p{0.75cm}}}[hvlines]
        \CodeBefore
            \rowcolor[rgb]{1.0, 1.0, 0.8}{1}
            \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8, 0.8, 1.0}{2-2, 3-3, 4-3, 4-4, 5-4, 6-5, 7-5,7-6, 7-7, 8-7, 9-8, 9-9, 9-10, 10-10}
        \Body
         Activity(2021) & Apr & May & June & July & Aug & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dec   \\
         Create research proposal & & & & & & & & &\\
         Create questions & & & & & & & & &\\
         Schedule interviews and conduct them & & & & & & & & &\\
         Obtain relevant financial information & & & & & & & & &\\ 
         Create and send surveys to third-party logistics providers & & & & & & & & &\\
         Create outline & & & & & & & & &\\
         Write first draft & & & & & & & & &\\
         Submission of first draft & & & & & & & & &\\
         Write final draft using feedback & & & & & & & & &\\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This table doesn't look too good. You may consider decreasing the no of horizontal and vertical lines used.

A better approach can be removing all vertical lines and most of the horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % both vertically and horizontally centered column

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{m{4cm}*{9}{C{0.75cm}}}
        \CodeBefore
            \rowcolor[rgb]{1.0, 1.0, 0.8}{1}
            \cellcolor[rgb]{0.8, 0.8, 1.0}{2-2, 3-3, 4-3, 4-4, 5-4, 6-5, 7-5,7-6, 7-7, 8-7, 9-8, 9-9, 9-10, 10-10}
        \Body
        \toprule
         Activity(2021) & Apr & May & June & July & Aug & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dec   \\\midrule
         Create research proposal & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{2-3}
         Create questions & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{3-4}
         Schedule interviews and conduct them & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{3-4}
         Obtain relevant financial information & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{4-5} 
         Create and send surveys to third-party logistics providers & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{5-7}
         Create outline & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{5-7}
         Write first draft & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{7-10}
         Submission of first draft & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\cmidrule{8-10}
         Write final draft using feedback & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15\\\bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output 2]

The entries in the month columns were used for better visual.

Comment: Excellent answer. The second table is amazing.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for your nice comment.