# Where can I find a template for a schedule such as the one in the screenshot?

Tags: tables

I found a really fancy table that I intend to copy but I can't find any information on how to do a similar one:

[image: Schedule I intend to copy]

Help would be very welcome, I'm on a rush!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately, this is not a "Please do this for me" site. You can try looking at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349433/125871) for some ways to get started and then ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: You may want to search for the term "gant chart". There are several packages such as `pgfgantt` available from CTAN that help create similar tables. For an overview of other approaches, you may be intersted in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624271/134144

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `pgfgantt` was already mentioned in the comments and is probably the most useful to draw any sort of timed plan that also allows updates to the current date, etc.

However a really simple approach like the table you presented, can also be created with a really simple solution like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs,calc,xcolor}

\newcommand{\Heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\timebar}[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}p{#1cm}@{}}{\textcolor{cyan}{\rule[0pt]{#1cm}{10pt}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}p{1cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}}
    \toprule
    &\Heading{Jul}&\Heading{Aug}&\Heading{Sep}&\Heading{Oct}&\Heading{Nov}&\Heading{Dec}&\Heading{Jan}\\
    \midrule
    Data Analysis Model & \timebar{3} & & & & \\
    Development \& Validation & & \timebar{3} & & &\\
    Results' Discussion & & & & \timebar{2} &\\
    Thesis Writing & & \timebar{5} \\
    Preparation of Presentation & & & & & & \timebar{2}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with gantt like bars]

Comment: You may not want to renew `\bar`. It might appear in the document elsewhere. Maybe use `\Bar` instead.

Comment: @SandyG sure, I forgot that a lot of people just copy&paste things that were meant as an example, not a real implementation. You could also parametrize the font size, instead of hard coding 10pt, because it was the size for the class used.